# Method not found: Akka.Pattern.CircuitBreaker.Create

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-persistence

I get above error when I'm trying to create a persisting actor with SQL server persistence.

EDIT: what's weird when I clone repositories akka and akka persistence sql server and attach then instead using nuget packages is working as expected.
I'm using followinf versions:
"Akka" Version="1.4.11"
"Akka.Persistence.SqlServer" Version="1.4.10"

```
 akka {
  persistence{
    journal {
            plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.sql-server"
        sql-server {
            # qualified type name of the SQL Server persistence journal actor
            class = "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"

            # dispatcher used to drive journal actor
            plugin-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"

            # connection string used for database access
            connection-string = "my con string"

            # default SQL commands timeout
            connection-timeout = 30s

            # SQL server schema name to table corresponding with persistent journal
            schema-name = dbo

            # SQL server table corresponding with persistent journal
            table-name = EventJournal

            # should corresponding journal table be initialized automatically
            auto-initialize = on

            # timestamp provider used for generation of journal entries timestamps
            timestamp-provider = "Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Journal.DefaultTimestampProvider, Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common"

            # metadata table
            metadata-table-name = Metadata
            
            # Recommended: change default circuit breaker settings
            # By uncommenting below and using Connection Timeout + Command Timeout
            # circuit-breaker.call-timeout=30s
        }
    }

    snapshot-store {
            plugin = "akka.persistence.snapshot-store.sql-server"
        sql-server {

            # qualified type name of the SQL Server persistence journal actor
            class = "my con string"

            # dispatcher used to drive journal actor
            plugin-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"

            # connection string used for database access
            connection-string = "xyz"

            # default SQL commands timeout
            connection-timeout = 30s

            # SQL server schema name to table corresponding with persistent journal
            schema-name = dbo

            # SQL server table corresponding with persistent journal
            table-name = SnapshotStore

            # should corresponding journal table be initialized automatically
            auto-initialize = on
            
            # Recommended: change default circuit breaker settings
            # By uncommenting below and using Connection Timeout + Command Timeout
            # circuit-breaker.call-timeout=30s
        }
    }
}
```

}

My coordinator is trying to create actor per message Id but it fails with error:

> Error while creating actor instance of type
> Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal with 1 args: (
> class : "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal,
> Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"
> plugin-dispatcher : akka.actor.default-dispatcher
> connection-string : "xyz"
> connection-timeout : 30s
> schema-name : dbo
> table-name : EventJournal
> auto-initialize : on
> timestamp-provider : "Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Journal.DefaultTimestampProvider,
> Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common"
> metadata-table-name : Metadata
> sequential-access : on
> )
> Cause::
> Akka.Actor.ActorInitializationException: Exception during creation
> ---> System.TypeLoadException: Error while creating actor instance of type Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal
> with 1 args: (  class :
> "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal,
> Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"
> plugin-dispatcher : akka.actor.default-dispatcher
> connection-string : "xyz"
> connection-timeout : 30s
> schema-name : dbo
> table-name : EventJournal
> auto-initialize : on
> timestamp-provider : "Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Journal.DefaultTimestampProvider,
> Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common"
> metadata-table-name : Metadata
> sequential-access : on
> )
> ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Akka.Pattern.CircuitBreaker..ctor(Int32, System.TimeSpan,
> System.TimeSpan)'.
> at Akka.Persistence.Journal.AsyncWriteJournal..ctor()
> at Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Journal.SqlJournal..ctor(Config journalConfig)
> at Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal..ctor(Config
> journalConfig)

```
public class MyCoordinatorActor : ReceiveActor
    {
        public MyCoordinatorActor ()
        {
            Receive<MyMessage>(message =>
            {
                var childName = message.Id.ToString();

                var child = Context.Child(childName);
                if (child.IsNobody())
                {
                    var props = Props.Create(() => new AuctionActor(childName));
                    child = Context.ActorOf(props, childName);
                }
                child.Tell(message);
            });
        }
    }

  

public class MyActor : ReceivePersistentActor
{
        private decimal _currentValue;
        public override string PersistenceId { get; }

        public AuctionActor(string Id)
        {
            PersistenceId = Id;
            Command<BidMessage>(message =>
            {
                if (message.Value > _currentValue)
                {

                    Persist(message, mssage =>
                    {
                        _currentValue = mssage.Value;
                       
                    });
     
                }
                else
                {
              
                }

            });
           
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran into this issue, which was the result of us changing some APIs inside the `CircuitBreaker` as part of Akka.NET v1.4.11: https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Persistence.SqlServer/issues/177

We just pushed Akka.Persistence.SqlServer 1.4.11 a couple of minutes ago: https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.Persistence.SqlServer/releases/tag/1.4.11 - upgrading to this version should resolve your issue.